# Qual a etimologia da expressão "estar pau a pau"

Tags: etimologia, expressões, expressões-idiomáticas

Eu queria saber qual foi a forma de surgimento da expressão "estar pau a pau". Ex:

> Nossa, olha só aqueles nadadores, eles estão pau a pau

Mais especificamente, gostaria de saber se tem alguma coisa a ver com o revesamento no atletismo (corrida), onde os competidores têm que correr com bastões nas mãos para poderem passar para a frente.

Comment: Curioso, não queres acrescentar na tua pergunta o significado de "pau a pau"? Significa "lado a lado"?

Comment: Também pode significar, aparentemente, itens de mesmo valor. "Ações pau a pau", ações de mesmo valor. https://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/pau+a+pau/  https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20121016135258AAHswdC